# Show that a set of matrices has empty interior

Tags: general-topology, matrices

I'm trying to show the following:

> Let $\mathcal{U}$ be the set of $2\times 2$ real matrices such that $A\in \mathcal{U}$ iff $A$ has only one (real) eigenvalue. Then, $\mathcal{U}$ has empty interior.

My attempt was to use the continuity and surjectivity of the functions trace and determinant, considering that $$\lambda^2-tr(A)\lambda+det(A)=0$$ where $\lambda$ represents the eigenvalue of $A$. But I couldn't make a good progress and I'm not sure my approach is right. I only got $det(A)\geq0$. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have $\operatorname{tr}(A)^2 = 4\operatorname{det}(A)$. Showing that the set has empty interior is the same as showing that the complement is dense. So we want to show that the equation can be broken by arbitrarily slight change of $A$. If $A$ is not diagonal, then any change in a non-diagonal element changes the determinant but does not change the trace. If $A$ is diagonal, then clearly changing one of the diagonal elements results in distinct eigenvalues.